# Align text using align* environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I would like to align text using the `align*` environment.

What I would like to do in the example below is to align the different elements inside the braces after `# meaning`. So, I would like to have `indefinite(?x)`, `masculine(?x)` and `singular(?x)` below each other and aligned.

I have tried inserting another `align*` environment, but this gives me the error: `Argument of \align* has an extra }`

How can I do this? If this can be done in another way, i.e. not using the `align*` environment, this is fine for me either.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document} 

\begin{footnotesize}
    \begin{align*}
    &\left[
        \begin{tabular}{l}
            \textbf{?un-word}\\
            \hline \hline
            args: \lbrack ?x \rbrack\\
            syn-cat: \\
            \qquad lex-cat: article \\
            \qquad number: singular \\
            \qquad gender: masculine \\
        \end{tabular}
    \right]
    \leftarrow
    &\left[
        \begin{tabular}{l}
            \textbf{?un-word}\\
            \hline \hline
            \# meaning: \{indefinite(?x), masculine(?x), singular(?x)\}\\
            \hline
            \# form: \{string(?un-word, un)\}\\
        \end{tabular}
    \right]
    \tag{un-cxn}
    \end{align*}
\end{footnotesize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's not possible to use `align` environments inside `tabular`, but you can use `tabular` inside other `tabular`s. In this case you can align all elements after `meaning` with a new `tabular` with option `[t]` to align its top line with previous text. The final brace `}` is included after last element, because I don't know how to align with bottom tabular line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document} 

\begin{footnotesize}
    \begin{align*}
    &\left[
        \begin{tabular}{l}
            \textbf{?un-word}\\
            \hline \hline
            args: \lbrack ?x \rbrack\\
            syn-cat: \\
            \qquad lex-cat: article \\
            \qquad number: singular \\
            \qquad gender: masculine \\
        \end{tabular}
    \right]
    \leftarrow
    &\left[
        \begin{tabular}{l}
            \textbf{?un-word}\\
            \hline \hline
            \# meaning: \{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
                                    indefinite(?x),\\ 
                                    masculine(?x),\\
                                    singular(?x)\}
                                    \end{tabular}\\
            \hline
            \# form: \{string(?un-word, un)\}\\
        \end{tabular}
    \right]
    \tag{un-cxn}
    \end{align*}
\end{footnotesize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is not what I mean in my question. I would like `indefinite(?x)`, `masculine(?x)` and `singular(?x)` to be below each other and aligned. The three elements inside the curly braces, after `# meaning` in the right part.

Comment: @JNevens Sorry, I've misunderstood the question. I've updated my answer, is it better now?

Comment: I would get rid of the `align` and use `equation` *without* the `&`s.

Comment: @Ignasi This is what I was looking for, thank you! @Werner In this example, the outer `align*` environment is indeed useless, but I have some bigger constructions like this where alignment is done on `left[`